# JFileChooser won't allow selection of directories

Tags: java, directory, jfilechooser

I want to use a `JFileChooser` in my program in order to choose a directory and process it. However, no matter what `FileFilter` I use for the file chooser, the `Open` button is locked when a directory is selected. Below is the code of my `FileFilter`.

```
this.fileChooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter()
{
    @Override
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return "Directories";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f)
    {
        return f.isDirectory();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [file selection mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode-int-)? The default is JFilesChooser.FILES_ONLY, which means your custom FileFilter is effectively ignored even though you return true for directories.

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

or

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

Comment: @Clashsoft: Please don't diminish Adam's help by saying "thanks for the answer anyway", please instead officially accept the answer and give him credit for his attempt to help you.

Comment: I wanted to wait if someone else makes a better answer, but here you go.

Comment: @Clashsoft: this is the canonical answer.